How to clip satellite base map into polygons
I'm trying to create a model to detect trees within the boundary of a country in QGIS 3.34. So far, I'm using the Google Maps Satellite base map from QuickMapServices. I created a vector layer where I drew polygons outlining trees.
I want to extract / clip parts of the base map that are within the polygons to use as training data. Sample of what the outlines look like:

Is there a way to do this with my current setup? Any other ideas for a solution like this?

Do you need an individual raster for each polygon, or a single raster containg the pixels inside all of the polygons combined?
